# Codeigniter load array results in different functions

Tags: arrays, function, codeigniter

I have more function where I need to read $data['getContacts'] more times, the code working correctly, but there is a clean and different method for call it?

thanks!

```
 class AppController extends CI_Controller {

        public $id;

        function __construct() {

           parent::__construct(); 

           $this->id =  !empty($this->input->post('id')) ? (int)$this->input->post('id', TRUE) : '';             

        }

           public function restoreCredit()
           {

               $data['getContacts'] = $this->appmodel->getContacts($this->id); //repeat here?

           if($data['getContacts']->status != false) :

                     $this->appmodel->restoreCredit($this->id);

           endif; 

           }

            public function createRandToken()
            {
                $data['getContacts'] = $this->appmodel->getContacts($this->id); //repeat here?
                    if(!empty($data['getContacts']) && $data['getContacts']->token == false): 

                      $this->appmodel->setRandUserToken($this->id);

                endif;  
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your could define a function `getContacts`. It will fetch `$contacts` first time from the DB, after that it will always returned the fetched Contacts.

```
<?php
class AppController extends CI_Controller
{

    public $id;
    public $contacts;

    function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->id = !empty($this->input->post('id')) ? (int) $this->input->post('id', TRUE) : '';
    }

    public function getContacts() {

        if( !empty ( $this->contacts) ) { //If its populated return from here.
            return $this->contacts;
        }

        $this->contacts = $this->appmodel->getContacts($this->id);
        return $this->contacts;
    }

    public function restoreCredit()
    {

        $data['getContacts'] = $this->getContacts();

        if ($data['getContacts']->status != false) :

            $this->appmodel->restoreCredit($this->id);

        endif;
    }

    public function createRandToken()
    {
        $data['getContacts'] = $this->getContacts();
        if (!empty($data['getContacts']) && $data['getContacts']->token == false) :

            $this->appmodel->setRandUserToken($this->id);

        endif;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because there are changes in 2 functions and a new function has been created.